# How to get historical events with the Tendermint websocket via /subscribe method?

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk

I am subscribing to the events of Tendermint (like new transactions) with the code below;

```
query := "tm.event='Tx'"
txs, err := client.Subscribe(ctx, "some-consumer", query)
```

or from terminal as;

```
wscat --connect ws://0.0.0.0:26657/websocket
> { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subscribe", "params": ["tm.event='Tx'"], "id": 1 }
```

I am getting the events as they arise but how can I get the historical event, e.g. starting from a specific block?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `HTTP` from `github.com/tendermint/tendermint/rpc/client/http`. Then you can make requests like `Block(context, height)`, `Tx(context, hash, prove)`, and many others!

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a push based solution rather than pull based like getting block periodically. Either with web socket or with gRPC if possible

Comment: I think you need to use github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/x/bank/types

Then you can use grpc via grpcurl or programmatically via Go. Here's an example from the documentation:
https://docs.cosmos.network/master/run-node/interact-node.html#using-grpc

Here's the protobuf documentation:
https://docs.cosmos.network/master/core/proto-docs.html

Comment: If you want to get historical data, then I don't know how to get it through the websocket. I don't think this can be done.